# What is the Material design grey color of icons in Android?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm looking for the default Material design grey color of icons in Android. I use two icons but for some reason one is black and one is grey (although they original should be both black) and they have the exact same code:

[image]

I want to set the default grey color. Where can I find it? Even the hex value should solve this problem.

Comment: https://material.io/resources/icons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an eyedropper tool I found the hex code for the grey envelope, it's `#737373`.

If you're doing design work installing a tool like [Color](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/color-by-fardos-color-pic/iibpgpkhpfggipbacjfeijkloidhmiei) helps when it comes to finding an element's hex color. It includes an eyedropper tool that lets you click an element and get it's hex color.

Comment: Chrome devtools has an eyedropper, no need for an extension for that

Answer (score 0):

For changing icon color try:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="your value"
    android:layout_height="your value"
    ...
    android:tint="YourColor"
    />
```